# Vivre à propos / vivre comme il faut

Tags: sens, traduction

Dans les *Essais*, Livre III, Chapitre XIII, Montaigne écrit, selon la traduction en français moderne faite par Andre Lanly :

> "Notre grand et glorieux chef-d’œuvre c’est de vivre à propos."

Selon la traduction faite par Guy de Pernon :

> "Le glorieux chef-d’œuvre de l’homme, c’est de vivre comme il faut."

Je n'ai pas trouvé le texte original en français du XVIe siècle.

Je ne sais pas quelle est la traduction la plus juste.

Savez-vous quelle est la différence entre *vivre à propos* et *vivre comme il faut* ?

Comment: Montaigne a écrit en français, Alors, traduction??

Comment: Oui, du français du XVI siècle au français moderne.

Comment: Nostre grand et glorieux chef-d’œuvre c’est vivre à propos. https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Essais/Livre_III/Chapitre_13 Texte établi par P. Villey et V. L. Saulnier, P. U. F., 1965 (Livre III, p. 470-496).

Comment: Tu pourras trouver les textes des éditions originales sur [Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&query=%28gallica%20all%20%22Essais%20de%20Michel%20de%20Montaigne%22%29&lang=fr&suggest=0). Va falloir affiner la recherche, mon lien est brut !

Comment: @None merci beaucoup ! À votre avis, y a-t-il une différence entre vivre à propos et vivre comme il faut ?

Comment: Bingo ! Édition originale de 1580 [Tome 1](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5781058d.r=Essais%20de%20Michel%20de%20Montaigne?rk=21459;2) [Tome 2](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5750609v.r=Essais%20de%20Michel%20de%20Montaigne?rk=42918;4), comme c'est passé à l'OCR tu pourras faire une recherche dans le texte. (Attention sur Gallica il y a parfois des erreurs dans le passage à l'OCR).

Comment: Faut réfléchir pour répondre, je ne peux pas faire ça du tac au tac comme de donner une direction !

Comment: @None Je comprends, merci infiniment pour le lien !

Answer (score 1):

« Vivre à propos » n'implique à première vue que des connotations d'ordre spirituel d'après l'ébauche de  définition qu'on en trouve dans les commentaires suivants.

> [Montaigne Traduit Du Japonais](https://www.leslibraires.fr/livre/940492-vivre-a-propos-montaigne-traduit-du-japonais-michel-de-montaigne-flammarion)
>
> […] en l’invitant à Vivre à propos – autrement dit : à vivre animés par une « sagesse gaie ». Car la philosophie n’est pas une affaire de petits bavards, mais de grands vivants : Montaigne se lit parce qu’on peut le vivre. Ces pages invitent à la vie philosophique.

Une analyse de Ian MacLean développée dans son étude de Montaigne, [*Montaigne Philosophe*](https://www.liberation.fr/livres/1996/09/12/un-savoir-vivreian-maclean-montaigne-philosophe-puf-philosophies-128-pp-45-f_182833/), permet de conclure que selon Montaigne,

> Philosopher devrait […] s'entendre non comme discourir, mais comme savoir vivre. (Marc RAGON)

Il n'est pas question bien sûr du nom « savoir-vivre » tel que défini dans le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/savoir-vivre) (Respect des règles d’usages du monde et des égards de politesse que les Hommes se doivent en société.), mais de la forme verbale constituée des verbes « savoir » et  « vivre ». L'homme qui sait vivre est celui qui sait apprécier la vie, mais évidemment, il y a tendance à ne considérer que le côté sensuel des chose dans l'usage de cette expression. Dans son acception pleine, cependant, il n'y a qu'un pas à franchir dans le sens de lui substituer « vivre comme il faut », laquelle expression, au contraire néglige plutôt le côté sensuel, mettant l'accent sur le côté moral et intellectuel. Cependant, Montaigne, ne fait pas de discrimination, et les deux aspects de la vie, le sensuel et le spirituel, sont les matières auxquelles s'appliquent le savoir vivre, ou le savoir vivre comme il faut si l'on doit recourir à cette dernière expression.

Dans cet [article](https://voilacestdit.blog4ever.com/vivre-a-propos-montaigne) se trouve le texte originel et une étude de l'idée que l'on doit rechercher dans l'expression originelle « vivre à propos ».

> Pour le plaisir de la lecture - ou de la relecture - voici un passage des Essais, Livre III, chapitre XIII, où Montaigne, nous incite, non pas tant à "vivre l'instant présent" [comme on trouve dans les ouvrages modernes] mais plus subtilement "vivre à propos" : "Notre grand et glorieux chef-d'oeuvre..."... "c'est vivre à propos", comme cela vient, en l'accueillant :
>
> > Quand je danse, je danse : quand je dors, je dors. Voire, et quand je me promène solitairement en un beau verger, si mes pensées se sont entretenues des occurrences étrangères quelque partie du temps : quelque autre partie, je les ramène à la promenade, au verger, à la douceur de cette solitude, et à moi [...]
> > Nous sommes de grands fous. Il a passé sa vie en oisiveté, disons-nous : je n'ai rien fait d'aujourd'hui. Quoi ? n'avez-vous pas vécu ? C'est non seulement la fondamentale, mais la plus illustre de vos occupations. Si on m'eût mis au propre des grands maniements, j'eusse montré ce que je savais faire. Avez-vous su méditer et manier votre vie ? vous avez fait la plus grande besogne de toutes [...]
> > Le glorieux chef-d'oeuvre de l'homme, c'est vivre à propos.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comme_il_faut)) **comme il faut** \kɔm‿il.fo\ — Note : Le verbe falloir s’y conjugue en temps et en mode.
>
> De la manière dont il convient que les choses soient faites, correctement, normalement, régulièrement, proprement, avec soin, en prenant garde.

On voit bien que dans cette définition il n'est nullement question de prendre les choses comme elles viennent, en les accueillant, ni plus que d'une « sagesse gaie », et nécessairement, ce n'est pas une expression qui couvre si bien l'idée au facettes variées qui a été celle de Montaigne, et que l'on trouve résumée dans son « vivre à propos », mais, évidemment, aucune expression ne peut prétendre accomplir cela.